# Can Arcane Armor replace a missing eye?

Tags: dnd-5e, armor, artificer, artificer-infusions

Arcane Armor states that it "replaces any missing limbs, functioning identically to a limb it replaces". Would this apply to a missing eye?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're asking? Say, is this for a (potential) upcoming character, or in response to something which has actually happened in a game (or something else?

Answer (score 25):

#### An eye is not a limb.

“Limb” is not a special game term in the rules. So, we understand it according to its usual English definition. Since we aren’t talking about tree branches, we must be talking about:

> A major appendage of human or animal, used for locomotion (such as an arm, leg or wing).

This is not describing an eye. Prosthetic eyes are a different magic item, in particular, the Ersatz Eye (common):

> This artificial eye replaces a real one that was lost or removed. While the ersatz eye is embedded in your eye socket, it can’t be removed by anyone other than you, and you can see through the tiny orb as though it were a normal eye.

Which, if you’re in need of an eyeball, common magic items can be made using the Replicate Magic Item infusion.

Comment: It may be worth noting that common (non-consumed) magic items are learnable as Infusions, though the exact usefulness of that will depend a bit on the context of the question (which I've asked for above).

Comment: @Someone_Evil Ah, right, thanks. Added a note about it.

Comment: Tails are usually also considered limbs, even if they are not used for locomotion mostly. Might you link the dictionary you used?

Comment: @Trish Tails are only limbs if they're jointed or prehensile.